# Scanner detection in angular 2+

Tags: jquery, angular, barcode-scanner

I have an input box that a user can scan (handheld scanner) or manually enter(keyboard) a UPC. If the user scans the UPC, I would like to automatically call a search function, but if manually entered, the user will have to hit a search button.
I have been able to find solutions for angularJS and jquery however nothing for angular 2+. Is there a solution that works like jquery scanner detection? Or does anyone know of a way to implement a solution in angular 2+, maybe a timer function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular inputs inherit properties from the abstract control directive that you can key in on. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective

I would simply access the onChange function, check if the form has been `touched`, `isDirty`, etc to see which one is not altered by programmatically altering the input, probably `touched`. If you that `touched` is false, and the value `onChange` is different than the initial value you can submit the search. That should only fire if the value of the form changes without you manually entering data, which would make `touched` true.

Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could instead just listen to the bar code input with a @HostListener.  I made a directive that I applied to the page I wanted the scanner to work on

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[appScanner]'})

export class ScannerDirective {
  combinedCode = null

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log(this.combinedCode);
    } else {
      if (this.combinedCode === null) {
        this.combinedCode = event.key;
      } else {
        this.combinedCode = this.combinedCode + event.key;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Then you can just have a regular form field for the typed input